# Enable WYSIWYG editor for Magento custom attribute?

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

How can I enable the WYSIWYG editor for a custom attribute (not dissimilar to short description and description) in Magento (CE 1.6.1.0)?

I've found documentation showing that it should be in between the 'position' and 'allow HTML tags on frontend' fields under 'frontend properties' in the attribute settings, but there isn't anything there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WYSIWYG is only available for "Text Area" type attributes.

Comment: Ah you might have the solution - just checked on my live installation of Magento and noticed there is both a 'text field' type and 'text area' type - as in HTML. I'll check tomorrow when I'm on my development machine, but I'm sure that's what I've missed. :-) Thanks.

Comment: There is an option to enable and disable WYSIWYG editor for text area type